# Unit test a component containing a ngbTypeahead

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ng-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I have a component that contains a form with 3 input texts. Two inputs are pure text boxes, and one is a text box with the ngbTypeahead diretive of ng-bootstrap.
My form is built using FormBuilder (reactive form).

```ts
 this.form = fb.group({
  department: [''],
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  location: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

My template looks like :

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name"/>
...
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="location"/>
...
<input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="department"
    [ngbTypeahead]="autocompleteDepartments"
    [resultFormatter]="formatDepartment"
    [inputFormatter]="formatDepartment"/>
```

The component contains functions for ngbTypeahead

```ts
autocompleteDepartments(text$: Observable<string>): Observable<Department> {
    ....
}
formatDepartment(department: Department) {
    return department.name;
}
```

So the this.form.department.value is not a string but a object like this :

```ts
interface Department {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  foo: boolean;
  bar: number;
  ...
}
```

All work fine.

Now I want to unit test my component and for that I need to set a value for each of the three inputs.
For the two pure inputs, no problem :

```ts
const nameHtmlEl = <HTMLInputElement>fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[formControlName="name"]')).nativeElement;
nameHtmlEl.value = "Toto";
nameHtmlEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

But for the input with the ngbTypeahead directive, I do not know how to set the value (that need to be a Department object and not a string) :
I tried that, but it does not work :

```ts
const departmentHtmlEl = /*<HTMLInputElement>*/ fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[formControlName="department"]')).nativeElement;
departmentHtmlEl.value = <Department>{id: 10, name: "Foo", ...};
departmentHtmlEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to simulate the selection of one of the filtered items for the Typeahead.

The way I would go about this is to still set key string that you are searching for:

```ts
departmentHtmlEl.value = 'Foo';
```

assuming you are searching on name.

then, I would simulate the selection. This you could do by

```ts
getWindowLinks(fixture.debugElement)[0].triggerEventHandler('click', {});
```

where getWindowLinks is:

```ts
function getWindowLinks(element: DebugElement): DebugElement[] {
  return Array.from(element.queryAll(By.css('button.dropdown-item')));
}
```

Also, you will have to use fakeAsync to make this work. Sample test will look something like this:

```ts
 it('sample test', fakeAsync(() => {
    const departmentHtmlEl = /*<HTMLInputElement>*/ fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[formControlName="department"]')).nativeElement;
    departmentHtmlEl.value = 'Foo';
    fixture.detectChanges();

    tick(300);
    // this should be more than the number on debounceTime you are using for the search

    getWindowLinks(fixture.debugElement)[0].triggerEventHandler('click', {});
    fixture.detectChanges();

    tick(300);

    // your expectation code here.
  }));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't work for me. After changing the value, detecting changes, and executing a long enough `tick()`, those `button.dropdown-item` options were still not in the DOM

Comment: Hi @JacobStamm, if you add the following after changing your value it should work. `departmentHtmlEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));`

Comment: Don't forget to call `flush()` after `tick` to flush the scheduler's queue.